# CAML OrderBy for SharePoint Recurring Calendar Event

Tags: sharepoint, calendar, caml

The following is the CAML query from a calendar view for a SharePoint list that I have.  I have added an OrderBy statement that references two custom columns within the list.

```
<Query>
    <Where>
        <DateRangesOverlap>
            <FieldRef Name="EventDate"/>
            <FieldRef Name="EndDate"/>
            <FieldRef Name="RecurrenceID"/>
            <Value Type="DateTime">
                <Month/>
            </Value>
        </DateRangesOverlap>
    </Where>
    <OrderBy>
        <FieldRef Name="MyOrder"/>
        <FieldRef Name="MyTitle"/>
    </OrderBy>
</Query>
```

The OrderBy statement works fine for all events that are **not** recurring.

Can I use OrderBy with recurring events?  If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Did you happen to try to sort descending by RecurrenceID? That field includes the date in the first half of the value.